# How to remove watermark on last page in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to remove a watermark on the last page of my PDF, but I can't detect the last page in the header Yes I can do it in the footer.

```
 protected $last_page_flag = false;
   
     public function Close() {
    $this->last_page_flag = true;
    parent::Close();
  }

    public function Footer(){
    if ($this->last_page_flag ){
//this work fine

}
}

//But I can't detect the last page in the header, which is where I put the watermark.

public function Header(){
        

$img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'marca_agua.jpg';
        $this->Image($img_file, 12, 80, 185, 180, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        $this->setPageMark();

//if I do
 if ($this->last_page_flag ){
//Do nothing...

}
        }
```

My pdf has a dynamic number of pages and I need to remove the watermark on the last one. How can I detect if it is the last page in the header?

Or how can I insert the watermark in a section other than the header?

Thanks! I am really desperate with this problem because it is the last thing I have left to deliver a job and I have been trying it for two days without a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the value of $tcpdflink to false in /tcpdf/tcpdf.php

```
/**
 * If true print TCPDF meta link.
 * @protected
 * @since 5.9.152 (2012-03-23)
 */
protected $tcpdflink = false;
```

Also (or instead), update the value on the constructor:

```
$this->tcpdflink = false;
```